# Postgres Check if IP (inet) is IN a list of IP Ranges

Tags: postgresql, ip-address, inet

I want to check if an IP exists in a range of ranges, eg: `SELECT * FROM ip_address WHERE ip IN (<list of ip ranges>)`

[Postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-net.html) states to use the << operator to check if an IP is contained within a single IP Range, eg: `inet '192.168.1.5' << inet '192.168.1/24'`, but I'm not sure how to use it on a list of ranges without having to construct an OR chain of <<'s.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
select inet '192.168.1.5' << any (array['192.168.1/24', '10/8']::inet[]);
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18486

Comment: Note that if the list can also contain exact non-range matches like '192.168.1.1', you should use `<<=` (contains or equals) rather than `<<` (contains). This caught me out.