# Saving IP address ranges as string in Postgresql will be comparable?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I'd like to save IP address ranges in 2 columns and determine regarding some IP address if it's in this range by "greater than" and "less than" operators.
Will it work if I save the ranges as VARCHAR ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944075/postgres-check-if-ip-inet-is-in-a-list-of-ip-ranges you can check if belongs to `array():inet[]`

Answer (score 2):

Postgres has [network address types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-net-types.html) that support those [operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-net.html).

Comment: But I'm working with Hibernate which , by default, doesn't support mapping from/to these network addresses types.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019866/hibernate-postgresql-network-address-type-inet-cdir

Comment: And if I prefer not to create a new custom class like the answer in this link, will the save as VARCHAR work ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it would not work. Comparing number in string is a bad idea, as `'11'` is considered smaller than `'2'` (comparing the 1st char, 2 > 1, so 2nd string is greater than the 1st one).  Should you not want to use the network type, you would have more luck using bigint with proper padding